# Best way to create a FAQ section in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 300 questions and answers and each of the questions fall in one of four categories. My question is what would be the best way to create web searchable pages for each 300 Q&A.

My first thought is to just do it simple and create one model. The one model will have question:string answer:text category:string and then input all the questions and answers in the database.

My second choice would be to create a category model and then a model for questions and answers.

My third choice is to create a JSON file with the questions and answers formatted then call on it through Javascript.

What would be the best way to achieve this while allowing search engines to rank each question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, go with **single model** `Faq` which contains all the required info i.e. `question`, `answer`, and `category`.

You don't need a separate model for categories if:

- The categories list is predefined (in which case you can use [enum type field](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)), AND
- Each category has *only* a name and **no** other attributes.

About JSON file, it will be difficult to add/remove FAQs in that. You will probably need to **push your code** after every change. With a model `Faq` in application, you can always do CRUD on FAQs easily.

So, the final structure should be like this:

```
class Faq
  # field :question
  # field :answer
  # field :category, type: :enum, values: %w[<category-names>]
end
```

And for rendering FAQs category-wise, you can always [group](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) on `category`.